# Changing DNS: Error 'DEPTH_ZERO_SELF_SIGNED_CERT'

Tags: node.js, dns, traefik

I am trying to change my DNS. My api project works fine.

But when I change those 4 lines in my `docker-compose.demo.yml` file:

```
-      - API_URI=https://api.demo.x.fr
-      - WEB_URI=https://app.demo.x.fr
+      - API_URI=https://api.demo.y.fr
+      - WEB_URI=https://app.demo.y.fr

-      - MINIO_HOST=media.demo.x.fr
+      - MINIO_HOST=media.demo.y.fr

-      - "traefik.http.routers.api-client.rule=Host(`api.demo.x.fr`)"
+      - "traefik.http.routers.api-client.rule=Host(`api.demo.y.fr`)"
```

and deploy it, my api crash on my demo server with this error:

```
yarn run v1.22.5
$ tsc && NODE_PATH=./build node build/index.js

node:internal/process/promises:246
          triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
          ^

Error: self signed certificate
    at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (node:_tls_wrap:1536:34)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:365:28)
    at TLSSocket._finishInit (node:_tls_wrap:950:8)
    at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (node:_tls_wrap:722:12) {
  code: 'DEPTH_ZERO_SELF_SIGNED_CERT'
}
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

I've tried to use this line of code `process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0";` as a solution specified in this post: https://github.com/request/request/issues/418 to solve my problem.

But I get this new error:

```
yarn run v1.22.5
$ tsc && NODE_PATH=./build node build/index.js
(node:38) Warning: Setting the NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED environment variable to '0' makes TLS connections and HTTPS requests insecure by disabling certificate verification.
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)

/usr/src/api/node_modules/minio/dist/main/xml-parsers.js:78
  var e = new errors.S3Error();
          ^
S3Error
    at Object.parseError (/usr/src/api/node_modules/minio/dist/main/xml-parsers.js:78:11)
    at /usr/src/api/node_modules/minio/dist/main/transformers.js:164:22
    at DestroyableTransform._flush (/usr/src/api/node_modules/minio/dist/main/transformers.js:88:10)
    at DestroyableTransform.prefinish (/usr/src/api/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_transform.js:129:10)
    at DestroyableTransform.emit (node:events:365:28)
    at prefinish (/usr/src/api/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:611:14)
    at finishMaybe (/usr/src/api/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:620:5)
    at endWritable (/usr/src/api/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:643:3)
    at DestroyableTransform.Writable.end (/usr/src/api/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:571:22)
    at IncomingMessage.onend (node:internal/streams/readable:690:10)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:471:28)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:377:35)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1312:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
  amzRequestid: null,
  amzId2: null,
  amzBucketRegion: null
}
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Answer (score 0):

My DNS were changed correctly for:

```
API_URI=https://api.demo.y.fr
WEB_URI=https://app.demo.y.fr
```

But not for:

```
MINIO_HOST=media.demo.y.fr
```

So this works for me:

```
API_URI=https://api.demo.y.fr
WEB_URI=https://app.demo.y.fr
MINIO_HOST=media.demo.x.fr
"traefik.http.routers.api-client.rule=Host(`api.demo.y.fr`)"
```